# PHP Laravel how to group date data into months and add Header

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a small `Laravel`-app where I want to display specific releases grouped by the month. Something like this:

```
January
11.1 - blabla
       more blablabla the same day

15.1 - blablabla

February
05.2 - blabla

etc...
```

So, In my Controller I just do this:

```
public function index() {

  $releases = Release::orderBy('release_date', 'asc')->get();

  return view('pages.index')->with('releases', $releases);
}
```

And In my blade view file I lopp through the data:

```
@foreach ($releases as $release)
     <div>
        <p>
            <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($release->release_date)->format('d. M')}}</span>&nbsp;
            <span>{{$release->artist}} - {{$release->album_title}} </span>
        </p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This gives me the correct data e.g a list of the DB-entries but as mentioned before, I want to group them by month and additionally add a header for each month.  How can I achieve that?

I'm using `Laravel 5.5` if that matters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index() {

    $releases = Release::orderBy('release_date', 'asc')
            ->get()->groupBy('release_date.month');

    return view('pages.index')->with('releases_groups', $releases);
}

@foreach ($releases_groups as $month => $releases_group)
    // just place group info here...
    @foreach ($releases_group as $release)
    <div>
        <p>
          <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($release->release_date)->format('d. M')}}</span>&nbsp;
          <span>{{$release->artist}} - {{$release->album_title}} </span>
        </p>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Try this.

Comment: The key is `groupBy('release_date.month')`

Comment: hmm, I get `Column not found` when trying this :-/

Comment: I had fixed it, place `->groupBy('release_date.month')` after `get()`, and everything will be all right.

Comment: ah I see but hmm... I don't get the months name from this... :s

Comment: Yeah, I had edited the code, the collection key is `month`, and it is an integer of `1~12`, but I don't know if this format is  what you want.

Comment: All available format are `month`, `localeMonth`, `shortLocaleMonth`, `englishMonth`, `shortEnglishMonth`, you can have a try and see which you want

Comment: Ah so how do I get the group info out then?

Comment: `@foreach ($releases_groups as $month => $releases_group)`, the `$month` is the only group info so far, hmm, is it not enough?

Comment: ah my bad, I just saw it :-) So now I just have to compare the integer value and return the correct string like 1 = January, 2 = February etc?

Comment: You don't need to do this, instead use a different format, for example, `->groupBy('release_date.englishMonth')`, the `$month` would be 'January', 'February', etc. All available month format have been listed before

Comment: After looking at the other answers, one important thing you should know is that, the `groupBy` is used to group you results set. It means that if you use `paginate` instead of `get`, same month of real life may be not group correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

**Table: releases**

```
id    |    released_at    |    bla_details    |    month_header_id
```

**Table: month_headers**

```
id    |    month(specific length int)    |    year(specific length int)    |    header
```

**Model: Release.php**

```
public function month_header() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Month');
}
```

**Model: MonthHeader.php**

```
public function releases() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Release');
}
```

**Helper: getMonthName($integer)**

**Controller: TempController.php**

```
public function temp()
{
    $response['month_headers'] = MonthHeader::all();
    return view('tempView', $response);
}
```

**Blade View: tempView.blade.php**

```
@foreach($month_headers as $header)
    {{getMonthName($header->month)." (".$header->header.")"}}
    <ul>
        @foreach($month_headers->releases() as $release)
            <li>{{date('d.m', strtotime($release->released_at))." - ".$release->bla_details}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

**View Output**

January (Jan Header)

- 11.1 - blabla
- 15.1 - blablabla

February (Feb Header)

- 05.2 - blabla
- 06.2 - blabla

etc...

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Very nice solution too! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest get your controller to do more work:

```
public function index() {

  // Here we get a distinct list of dates in your format
  $releaseDates = Release::Selectraw('date_format(date(release_date),"%d.%m") as Date')->distinct()->get();

  // For each date we now get the elements for each date and put them as an array entry in to the date under a 'data' section
  foreach($releaseDates as $releaseDate){
     $releaseDate['data'] = Release::whereraw('date_format(date(release_date),"%d.%m") = '.$releaseDate->Date)->get();
  }

  // Pass the data to the view as before but with new name
  return view('pages.index')->with('releaseDates', $releaseDates );
}
```

Then in your view:

```
// For each release date first
@foreach ($releaseDates as $releaseDate)
     <div>
        <p>
            //Print out the date as requested
            <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($releaseDate->Date)->format('d. M')}}</span>&nbsp;
            // Now loop through each record nested as an array inside the date
            @foreach($releaseDate['data'] as $data)
                 <span>{{$data->artist}} - {{$data->album_title}} </span>
                 <br>
            @endforeach
        </p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Now each entry has the same date :-)

Comment: @ST80 I've added some comments, note the second foreach loop in your blade view now which is needed to pull out the records under each date.

Answer (score 0):

UNION ALL is best way to group header and ggroup date data into months

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection::groupBy() method like this:

```
$releases->groupBy(function(Release $release) {
     return $release->release_date->format('F');
});
```

Now *$releases* is Collection with month name as key and Collection (array of Releases) as value like this:

```
[
    "January" => Collection{Release, Release, Release},
    "February" => Collection{Release, Release, Release},
    ...
]
```

Don't forget years ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ->get()->groupBy('release_date') method it returns objects by date.

For Example;

```
public function index() {

  $releases = Release::orderBy('release_date', 'asc')->get()->groupBy('release_date');

  return view('pages.index')->with('releases', $releases);
}
```

I think solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (in your Controller)?

```
$groupedReleases = null;

foreach ($releases as $release) {
    $date = $release->release_date->format('your desired format');
    $groupedReleases[$date][] = $release;
}

return $groupedReleases;
```

Answer (score 0):

> See the below select function with raw query where i added "Month Name" and "month number" for your reference.Please check the output.Hope this will help you

```
$releases = Release::select(DB::raw('some_field, MONTHNAME(release_date) as month_name, MONTHNAME(release_date) as month'))
                          ->orderBy('release_date', 'asc')->get();
```

> You may use GroupBy if you are sure that there is not more than one release on same date.

```
    $releaseArray=[];
    if(!empty($releases)) {
        foreach($releases as $release){
            $releaseArray[$release->month][] = $release;
        }
    }

    print_r($releaseArray);
```

Now you can pass the $releaseArray to the view and iterate for the releases grouped by month.